# Rspec and FactoryGirl: stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to rails and working on embedding associations into my models for my API. However adding the embeds has caused my specs to fire the following error:
Rails: 4.2.3 Ruby:2.2.1 Rspec: 3.3.2 FactoryGirl: 4.5.0

```
  1) Api::V1::ProductsController GET #show returns the information about a reporter on a hash
     Failure/Error: get :show, id: @product.id
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
```

I think from looking at other answers on stack overflow that there is a problem with how I'm using my factories in my tests.

Here are the models:
product.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :auth_token, uniqueness: true


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_create :generate_authentication_token!

  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

  def generate_authentication_token!
    begin
      self.auth_token = Devise.friendly_token
    end while self.class.exists?(auth_token: auth_token)
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :user_id, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 },
    presence: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and the factories:
users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { FFaker::Internet.email }
    password "12345678"
    password_confirmation "12345678"
  end
end
```

products.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    title { FFaker::Product.product_name }
    price { rand() * 100 }
    published false
    user
  end
end
```

and here is the spec I'm getting all of the errors from.
products_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::ProductsController do

  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @product = FactoryGirl.create :product
      get :show, id: @product.id
    end

    it "returns the information about a reporter on a hash" do
      product_response = json_response[:product]
      expect(product_response[:user][:email]).to eql @product.user.email
    end

    it "has the user as an embeded object" do
      product_response = json_response[:product]
      expect(product_response[:user][:email]).to eql @product.user.email
    end

    it { should respond_with 200 }
  end

  describe "GET #index" do
    before(:each) do
      4.times { FactoryGirl.create :product }
      get :index
    end

    it "returns 4 records from the database" do
      products_response = json_response
      expect(products_response[:products]).to have(4).items
    end

    it "returns the user object into each product" do
      products_response = json_response[:products]
      products_response.each do |product_response|
        expect(product_response[:user]).to be_present
      end
    end


    it { should respond_with 200 }
  end

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "when is succesfully created" do
      before(:each) do
        user = FactoryGirl.create :user
        @product_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for :product
        api_authorization_header user.auth_token
        post :create, { user_id: user.id, product: @product_attributes }
      end

      it "renders the json representation for the product record just created" do
        product_response = json_response[:product]
        expect(product_response[:title]).to eql @product_attributes[:title]
      end

      it { should respond_with 201 }

    end
    context "when is not created" do
      before(:each) do
        user = FactoryGirl.create :user
        @invalid_product_attributes = { title: "Smart TV", price: "Twelve dolalrs" }
        api_authorization_header user.auth_token
        post :create, { user_id: user.id, product: @invalid_product_attributes }
      end

      it "renders an errors json" do
        product_response = json_response
        expect(product_response).to have_key(:errors)
      end

      it "renders the json errors on why the product could not be created" do
        product_response = json_response
        expect(product_response[:errors][:price]).to include "is not a number"
      end

      it { should respond_with 422 }
    end

  end

  describe "PUT/PATCH #update" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      @product = FactoryGirl.create :product, user: @user
      api_authorization_header @user.auth_token
    end

    context "when is successfully updated" do
      before(:each) do
        patch :update, { user_id: @user.id, id: @product.id,
                         product: { title: "An expensive TV"} }
      end

      it "renders the json representation for the updated user" do
        product_response = json_response[:product]
        expect(product_response[:title]).to eql "An expensive TV"
      end

      it { should respond_with 200 }
    end

    context "when is not updated" do
      before(:each) do
        patch :update, { user_id: @user.id, id: @product.id,
                         product: { price: "two hundred" } }
      end

      it "renders an errors json" do
        product_response = json_response
        expect(product_response).to have_key(:errors)
      end

      it "renders the json errors on why the user could not be created" do
        product_response = json_response
        expect(product_response[:errors][:price]).to include "is not a number"
      end

      it { should respond_with 422 }
    end
  end

  describe "DELETE #destroy" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      @product = FactoryGirl.create :product, user: @user
      api_authorization_header @user.auth_token
      delete :destroy, { user_id: @user.id, id: @product.id }
    end

    it { should respond_with 204 }
  end

end
```

And the Products Controller:

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_with_token!, only: [:create, :update]
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    respond_with Product.all
  end

  def create
    product = current_user.products.build(product_params)
    if product.save
      render json: product, status: 201, location: [:api, product]
    else
      render json: { errors: product.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  def update
    product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
    if product.update(product_params)
      render json: product, status: 200, location: [:api, product]
    else
      render json: { errors: product.errors }, status: 422
    end

  end

  def destroy
    product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
    product.destroy
    head 204
  end

  private

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price, :published)
    end
end
```

user_serializer.rb

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :auth_token
  has_many :products
end
```

EDIT: Adds Products Controller

Comment: Can you post your `ProductsController`?

Comment: You can test your factories in rails console. And I would check how works `generate_authentication_token!` method because exactly this method can cause infinite cycle

Comment: Is your code for Product model complete? I would suspect that the "stack level too deep" happens in before(:each) for FactoryGirl.create(:product). It could happen when you try to create or update something in product's callbacks and, as a result, those callbacks are triggered in an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, what does this do: 
    `end while self.class.exists?(auth_token: auth_token)`